# JQuery Ajax Call: How to fetch JsonArray?

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax, web-services

I am finding an issue while i am trying to fetch data from webservice which returns data in the form of `JsonArray(com.google.gson.JsonArray)`.
I get `undefined` while i receive data in `UI`.
In `java` i get below `exception`:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.IllegalStateException) (through reference chain: com.google.gson.JsonArray["asString"])
```

I have tried various ways but nothing seems to work. Please find the code i have tried.

Java

```
@GET
@Path("/fetchData")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JsonArray fetchData(@QueryParam("term") String id) 
{
    List<Object[]> listObj = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    JsonArray jsonArrayObj = new JsonArray();
    try
    {           
        listObj = manager.planningData(id.toString());
        for (Object[] obj : listObj) 
        {
            JsonObject jsonObj = new JsonObject();
            if(obj[0]!=null)
            {
                jsonObj.addProperty("ID", obj[0].toString());
            }

            jsonArrayObj.add(jsonObj);
        }
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    return jsonArrayObj;
}
```

JQuery

```
 $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : contextPath+'/rest/fetchDataPlan/fetchData?value='+valueId+'',
            dataType:'json',
            data : {
term:valueId,
            },
            success : function(data) {
                if (data) 
                {
                    console.log("test");
                }
                else 
                {
                    console.log("no work");
                }
            },
            error : function(err) {
                console.log("error occurred  "+err.message);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why are you swallowing the Exception?

Comment: Added the java exception as well @StephanHogenboom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JsonArray` needs to be parsed into a `list` in `java` and then returned. Then it worked fine.

```
ArrayList<Object> yourArray = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArrayObj, new TypeToken<List<Object>>(){}.getType());
```